# jquery-autocomplete with json array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-autocomplete

I was wondering how I would be able to get this working? I've read the demo files, but I'm curious if there is a way to make it work like this. I've got one php file that is something like this

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Locations ORDER BY City";
foreach($DBH->query($query) as $row)
{
    $array[] = $row['City'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

and some js

```
$('.searchbox').autocomplete('test.php', {minChars: 3,});
```

When I test it, I type in three letters, and instead of suggestions, I get the whole json array. I know that it's possible for this jquery-autocomplete to work with local data, but I just don't know how. https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete/ is the source, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/doc/jquery.autocomplete.txt) say you should set a `remoteDataType` option whose value is `json` if your backend is returning a JSON Array:

> remoteDataType  (default value: false)
>
> If this is set to 'json', the autocompleter expects a JSON array from the server. Any other
>   settings, it defaults to the native text format using lineSeparator and Cellseparator (see below).

E.g.

```
$('.searchbox').autocomplete('test.php', {
  minChars: 3,
  remoteDataType: 'json'
});
```

Also, your server-side query should make use of the `q` parameter that the autocompleter sends in the `GET` to only return the results that match what has been typed in.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid GET because that would raise the complexity of the php file. It really is just a simple array on a table, and I think pulling data from it once would be less load on the server. Anyhow, specifying remoteDataType worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you provide your url 'test.php' as a source for the autocompletion, your page must compute the names finishing by the provided 'term' request parameter.

From [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) :

> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to
>   point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the
>   same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete
>   plugin does not filter the results, instead the request parameter
>   "term" gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use
>   for filtering the results. The data itself can be in the same format
>   as the local data described above.

That means you must use the `term` request parameter in your SQL query to filter the results, for example

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Locations where City like '".$term."%' ORDER BY City";
```

Answer (score 0):

Send Your input text as GET variable to your test.php file and apply filter to your query using that variable.